# Changesets for many-to-many relationships

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Following along with [José's upserts post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/12/many-to-many-and-upserts/) I have a many-to-many relationship between two schemas - Technology and Jobs like so:

```
defmodule JobJawn.Listing.Job do
  @moduledoc """
  A job is a position for which a JobJawn user might want to apply.  This is the
    central model for the system - meaning it's the reason a user might want to
    visit the system.
  """

  use Ecto.Schema

  alias JobJawn.Directory.Company
  alias JobJawn.Listing.{
          Discipline,
          EmploymentType,
          RoleType,
          Technology,
          Title}

  schema "listing_jobs" do
    field :date_missing, :naive_datetime
    field :name, :string
    field :url, :string

    belongs_to :company, Company
    belongs_to :discipline, Discipline
    belongs_to :employment_type, EmploymentType
    belongs_to :role_type, RoleType
    belongs_to :title, Title

    many_to_many :technologies,
                 Technology,
                 join_through: "listing_jobs_technologies"

    timestamps()
  end
end


defmodule JobJawn.Listing.Technology do
  @moduledoc """
  Technology serves as a tag to help JobJawn users interested in a certain
  technlogy (Elixir, Erlang, Python, C#, F#, etc) locate relevant positions
  """

  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "listing_technologies" do
    field :name, :string
    field :job_count, :integer, virtual: true

    many_to_many :jobs, JobJawn.Listing.Job, join_through: "listing_jobs_technologies"

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

I keep getting validation errors when creating a changeset for jobs...

```
tech = JobJawn.Listing.Technology |> limit(1) |> JobJawn.Repo.one
JobJawn.Listing.Job
|> limit(1)
|> preload(:technologies)
|> JobJawn.Repo.one
|> change
|> put_assoc(:technologies, with: [tech])
```

will hand me an invalid changeset:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{},
 errors: [technologies: {"is invalid", [type: {:array, :map}]}],
 data: #JobJawn.Listing.Job<>, valid?: false>
```

I have no idea why.

This repo is public if it helps: https://github.com/mcelaney/job_jawn/commit/f408505d165ae71947858676922cf067fe1cc413

Comment: I think the call to `put_assoc` should be: `|> put_assoc(technologies, [tech])`

Comment: Ugh - I'm an idiot...

Comment: put_assoc has a different syntax than cast_assoc - can you rephrase as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Building the changeset should pass the list of `[tech]` as the last argument to `put_assoc`

```
tech = JobJawn.Listing.Technology |> limit(1) |> JobJawn.Repo.one

JobJawn.Listing.Job
|> limit(1)
|> preload(:technologies)
|> JobJawn.Repo.one
|> change
|> put_assoc(:technologies, [tech]) # <-- with: keyword removed
```